# How to change BottomAppBar orientation from code?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

The orientation of the application is portrait, so the automatic rotation provided by the operating system does not work. Is it possible to rotate the BottomAppBar from code?

**Orientation = Portrait**

```
DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Portrait;
```

I can rotate elements with animations and visual states, but not the BottomAppBar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Supported orientations property in Windows Phone 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827697/how-to-set-supported-orientations-property-in-windows-phone-8-1)

Comment: It is not duplicated. I need to rotate the application bar when the orientation of the page is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do this. You either rotate the whole page or nothing. Alternatively you can rotate the content using a translate transform, but nothing you can do about the appbar.